# Show context of match in search result

Tags: search

I'm currently implementing a search function on a website based on craft, and I was wondering if there was a way of actually showing a small snippet of text that shows in what context the search actually matched.

At the moment the result simply returns the corresponding `{{entry.title}}`, however I would like the result to also display something like `[...] a chain of mountains with the highest *peak* being around x-thousand metres [...]` when 'peak' was the search term.

Is there any way to achieve this within Craft?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is. There is a plugin called Weighted Search which I have used a few times which does exactly that. https://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins/weighted-search

Comment: That's great, I'll have a look at it. Thanks Laura!

Comment: No problem. Happy to help.